# Searchview filter not working with list containing parsed JSON but works with non-JSON List

Tags: android, android-studio

This is my MainActivity.java. The part that is the issue is getVolley() method. Filling up the List liste with parsed JSON data renders the SearchView unusable (Will not filter the results). Typing anything into the SearchView while the List is filled with JSON data completely removes everything in the List. However if i comment out the JSON section and uncomment the commented section the SearchView will work. The List is exactly the same and the only difference is that i either get the data from JSON or the commented out code block at the bottom.

```
        private void getVolley(){
            liste = new ArrayList<>();
            RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());

            JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null,
                    new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                            try {
                                JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("entries");
                                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                                    JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                                    liste.add(new Recycler(jsonObject.getString("navn")));
                                    recyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                }
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    error.printStackTrace();
                }
            });
            queue.add(request);

/*
            liste = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
                if (i == 1)
                liste.add(new Recycler( "en"));
                if (i == 2)
                    liste.add(new Recycler( "to"));
                if (i == 3)
                    liste.add(new Recycler( "tree"));
                if (i == 4)
                    liste.add(new Recycler( "fire"));
                if (i == 5)
                    liste.add(new Recycler( "fem"));
            }
*/
        }
```

This is the List using the JSON part.
https://gyazo.com/885e6acc0e6b25b6227b520c4be550fe

Here is the same list using the bottom code block which works.
https://gyazo.com/9fc6cc35780efd8ff284f8275840bead

If i have not provided enough information please let me know.

This is the Recycler Model

```
public class Recycler {
    private String navn;

    public Recycler(String navn) {
        this.navn = navn;
    }


    public String getNavn() {
        return navn;
    }

    public void setNavn(String navn) {
        this.navn = navn;
    }
}
```

This is where i Initialize RV. This method is just called in onCreate

```
    private void setRecyclerView() {
//Kaller på volley
        getVolley();
        RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.holder);

        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        recyclerAdapter = new RecyclerAdapter(liste);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerAdapter);
    }
```

This is the Adapter Code

```
public class RecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder> implements Filterable {

    private List<Recycler> liste;
    private List<Recycler> fullListe;

    RecyclerAdapter(List<Recycler> liste) {
        this.liste = liste;
        fullListe = new ArrayList<>(liste);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.test_tekst, parent, false);
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(view);
        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Recycler recycler = liste.get(position);
        holder.textView.setText(recycler.getNavn());
    }

    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView textView;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            textView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView123);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return liste.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        return exampleFilter;
    }
    private Filter exampleFilter = new Filter() {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence charSequence) {
            List<Recycler> filtrert = new ArrayList<>();

            if (charSequence == null || charSequence.length() == 0) {
                filtrert.addAll(fullListe);
            } else {
                String filterPattern = charSequence.toString().toLowerCase().trim();
                for (Recycler navn : fullListe) {
                    if (navn.getNavn().toLowerCase().contains(filterPattern)) {
                        filtrert.add(navn);
                    }
                }
            }

            FilterResults resultat = new FilterResults();
            resultat.values = filtrert;

            return resultat;
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence charSequence, FilterResults resultat) {
            liste.clear();
            liste.addAll((List) resultat.values);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    };


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a concurrency problem, since getVolley starts a AsyncTask when you create the adapter the line `fullList = new ArrayList(liste)` copys the content of a empty array (that will be filled later) to the list that you want to be the full one, you must do something like this:

(considering you make fullListe public)

```
           public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                try {
                    JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("entries");
                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        liste.add(new Recycler(jsonObject.getString("navn")));
                    }

                    recyclerAdapter.fullListe.addAll(liste); // here you add the contets to the full list later after it has been created
                    recyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
```

And it should already work

Answer (score 1):

Try to call `notifyDataSetChanged` outside of `for` loop

```
private void setRecyclerView() {
    liste = new ArrayList<>();
    RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.holder);

    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    recyclerAdapter = new RecyclerAdapter(liste);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerAdapter);

    //Kaller på volley
    getVolley();
}
```

Here is the `Volly` call

```
private void getVolley() {
    liste.clear();
    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
    String url = "https://hotell.difi.no/api/json/mattilsynet/smilefjes/tilsyn";
    JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    try {
                        JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("entries");
                        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                            liste.add(new Recycler(jsonObject.getString("navn")));
                        }

                        recyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            error.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
    queue.add(request);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Unfortunately that did not work :(

Comment: Add your `Recycler` model. Also the initialization pard of RV

Comment: Ok, Is that what you were looking for? (I've edited the post)

Comment: That did not work either unfortunately. I still get the same result.

Comment: I think `notifyDataSetChanged ` not working properly. Could you try with your fixed items in the same order

Comment: Interesting, when i do that the fixed items also stop working.

Comment: Yes, It's a problem of `notifyDataSetChanged `. Without Volley it is a synchronous process. That's why it's worked previously. Please add your Adapter code to investigate

Comment: The issue has been resolved. Thank you so much for taking the time out of your day to help me :)

Comment: I am checking the implementation. It's working fine in my side. If you have time check it there: https://github.com/asad-zaman/SO-58941991